# nginx getimagesize from local server: 403

Tags: php, nginx, bots, http-status-code-403, getimagesize

I have a 403 error when trying to use the PHP function getimagesize on nginx based web server:

```
list($imageWidth, $imageHeight) = getimagesize($imagesSource['Main']);
```

Where $imageSource['Main'] is like:

```
https://mywebsite/include/php/render/canvas/VR/2/image/U35p/ver//bgColor/ffffff/widthMM/300/heightMM/388/aube-sunny.jpg
```

It's an image generated by PHP-imagick module and is not locally available. This image can be opened by a browser with no problem.

To generate this image which go through 404. Nginx is configured like that:

```
error_page 404 = /url_rewriting.php;
```

And in the file `url_rewriting.php`, we analyse the URL to see if it's real 404 or an image which must be generated:

```
if((isset($urlHash[2]) && $urlHash[2] === 'render')) {
...
    header('Status: 200 OK', false, 200);
    chdir('include/php/render/'.$_GET['render']);
    require ('include/php/render/'.$_GET['render'].'/render_img.php');
    exit;
}
```

All is working fine but not the getimagesize from my own server.

What is strange is that it's working on my development environment which has the same versions of nginx and PHP and pretty the same configuration.

It might a a configuration issue or a right issue on a certain file but I don't know where to check.

Comment: have you enabled `allow_url_fopen = On` in php.ini?

Comment: If you solved the problem post the solution as regular answer. Dobot edit the question as you just did

Comment: If I edit the question, there is no "Answear your own question". I have this option only on a new question!